# How to get Azure join date and account that joined?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Hi I am trying to get through powershell the Join Date for all our Azure AD only devices and if possible the account that joined the device?

Get-AzureADDevice and $_.DeviceTrustType do not hold this information.

Dsregcmd only holds registered date - I am hoping to get the actual AD Azure join date and account. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have one **Azure AD joined device** in my directory like below:

[image]

To know the device details like **`join date`** and **`account`** that performed this, you can check **Audit Logs** like below in Portal:

[image]

Mostly **`joined`** date and **`registered`** date will be same with seconds' gap.

To get the same details via **PowerShell**, you can execute below command like this:

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs | where-object Category -eq "Device" | select activityDisplayName,activityDateTime,InitiatedBy | ft
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get `full` details of **specific** activity like **`Register device`**, you can filter the command like below:

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Register device' " | where-object Category -eq "Device" | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get `full` details of **specific** activity like **`Add device`**, you can filter the command like below:

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Add device' " | where-object Category -eq "Device" | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]